# Angular 4 Http TypeError: Cannot read property 'response' of undefined

Tags: angular

I get this error `TypeError: Cannot read property 'response' of undefined` when doing a `http.get` inside of a unit test. Below is the complete unit test:-

```
import {TestBed} from '@angular/core/testing';
import {BaseRequestOptions, ConnectionBackend, Http, HttpModule, RequestOptions} from '@angular/http';

let http: Http;

describe('Quick', specDef);

function specDef() {
    beforeEach(setup);

    it('test', test);
}

function setup() {

    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
        imports: [HttpModule],
        providers: [Http,
                    ConnectionBackend,
                   {provide: RequestOptions, useClass: BaseRequestOptions}
                   ]
    });
    http = TestBed.get(Http);
}

function test() {
    http.get('http://a_url_to_use')
        .subscribe(res => {
             console.log(res);
        });
}
```

And the `console.log` statement never executes.

Why is this occurring? And what can I do to fix it?

Comment: Have you tried using something like postman to confirm that your GET /a_url_to_use is returning data?

Comment: what does the component you are testing look like? the get is either not returning anything (or you need a return statement there)

Comment: I've created a very similar unit test using HttpClient instead and that worked. I suspect it's something to do with creating the right providers but searching for examples clarify my suspicions yielded nothing.


This is going to part of a service class where the remote server requires authentication credentials with each call after the initial login call.

Comment: @FussinHussin the unit test code shown above is an end-to-end test on a live URL to make sure I understand how to code it.

Comment: @user223364 I agree with Erica Grant, you should try a curl get from your terminal, check what the server is returning

Comment: I did do a `curl get` to first confirm the URL is indeed alive before I started writing the code.